# WPF: Binding shortcut key to button based on button content

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to bind a shortcut key to a button using the content of the button to look up the appropriate shortcut.

I have a dictionary in the code-behind of strings and associated shortcut keys. It's no problem to pull out the key by referring to the dictionary and key explicitly.

The following example works:

```
<Button Content="Picture"
        Command="{Binding TestCmd}">
   <Button.InputBindings>
       <KeyBinding Key="{Binding Shortcuts[Picture]}"
                   Command="{Binding Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}"/>
   </Button.InputBindings>
</Button>
```

What I want to do use the button content as the key for looking up the shortcut. In essence `Key="{Binding Shortcuts[BUTTON.CONTENT]}"` but correct XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this can be done in a XAML-only way. One possible solution is to write a converter for this.

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Picture" Command="{Binding TestCmd}">
    <Button.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}}">
            <KeyBinding.Key>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DictionaryMultiValueConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Shortcuts" />
                    <Binding Path="Content" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </KeyBinding.Key>
        </KeyBinding>
    </Button.InputBindings>
</Button>
```

And the converter:

```
public class DictionaryMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(values.Length != 2)
            throw new ArgumentException(@"DictionaryMultiValueConverter needs exactly two values", "values");

        var dict = values[0] as IDictionary;
        var key = values[1];

        return dict != null && key != null && dict.Contains(key) 
            ? dict[key] 
            : DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The converter gets your `Dictionary` as its first value and the key to select as its second value. It then returns the value with that passed in key from the `Dictionary`.

Comment: Thanks. A problem I've found with this whole approach is that the button has to be in focus to hear key presses. So I'm going to go a completely different direction and leverage a custom keypress thing that is already working. But thanks again!